# How to send data via post after serialize?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been wondering myself if there is a way to send a data after serialize.

Let me explain, I'm sending data this way:

```
var serialize = $('#foo').serialize();

$.post( "foo.php", serialize, function( arrRetorn, textStatus ){
    ...
}
```

I've tried something like this:

```
$.post( "foo.php", serialize, 
    {
        textarea: $('textarea').val()
    }, 
    function( arrRetorn, textStatus ){
    ...
}
```

Obviously it won't work, because the serialize also sent the data.

Is there a way to do this without have to pass all the input's name on post data?

Comment: First serialize, then send serialized data. Just serialize form with all inputs instead of serialize each input separately.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
var serialize = $('#foo').serialize();
serialize.textarea = $('textarea').val();

$.post( "foo.php", serialize, function( arrRetorn, textStatus ){
   ...
}
```

Comment: It worked! I also find out that if I use `.serializeArray()` instead `.serialize()` and do this `serialize.push($('textarea').val())` it works too. But your solution is better! Thanks

Comment: hopefully you can check mark my answer...